# Why initial memory of the OTP23 64bit Erlang node is twice as much as OTP 20 64bit node?

Tags: memory, memory-management, erlang, erlang-otp

When I start an Erlang (OTP 20.2) node of 32-bit type consuming ~9 MB (erlang:memory() -> Total=9468168) and for the 64Bit type node size is ~15MB.

But when I start the **Erlang OTP 23** (erts 11.1.7) **64-Bit** type node memory size is ~30MB.

**Why it is increased by double in OTP 23 version??**

Note: Even with default apps started are stdlib and kernel in erts 11.1.7 but in OTP 20.2 (erts 9.2) sasl also started).

**Is there any way to restrict the initial memory of the Erlang node?**

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and time.

Comment: What's about 32-bit OPT 23?

Comment: I don't have the environment to check it

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it would consume 18MB which would be twice more than the 32bit OPT 20.2, so the ratios would be the same.

Comment: is there any known reason to take the memory twice?

Comment: Well, with 64-bit, everything is basically twice as large :-)

Comment: OK, If we compare only 64 bit, why OTP23 has 2x times of OTP20?